# Embedding chatbox in any webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a chatbot which is delivered inside a bootstrap  [model](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/) on my web page. So it is like a popup in my webpage with an angular-js controller to deliver and manage content in the chat.

The web page has normal JS and CSS dependencies like angular and bootstrap.

Now, I want to package my chatbot into a js script to deliver it on any webpage using a script tag(or embed maybe?). I am not able to find any help on google or stackoverflow on how to package that app to embed it into other websites.

Thanks in advance.